# Problem with HTML - button being autoclicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on CS50 Week8 problem set.  In the following code, I have a dropdown list and a button, and the link embedded in the latter depends on the former.  For some reason the button gets automatically clicked without being intended.  Any idea why this is going wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Justin's Homepage</title>
    </head>
    <body id="homepage">
        <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to Justin's Homepage!</h1>
        <p class="p1">Where would you like to travel next?</p>
        <select class="p1" id="location">
            <option value="interlaken">1. Interlaken</option>
            <option value="hokkaido" selected>2. Hokkaido</option>
            <option value="croatia.html">3. Croatia</option>
        </select>
        <div id="confirm">
            <form>
                <button class="p1" type="button" onclick="gotosite(); return false">Confirm!</button>
                <script>
                    var location = document.getElementById("location").value;
                    function gotosite(){
                        location.href(location + ".html");
                    }
                </script>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `location.href(location + ".html");` — `location.href` isn't a function, so that will throw an exception.

Comment: `var location = document.getElementById("location").value;` overrides `window.location` and you are reading the value when page renders

Answer (score 1):

You need the get the value of the `select` field when someone clicks on the Submit button not on loading the page so you should keep the `value` getting logic inside the function.

I have also updated the `window.location.href` thing, have a look.

This is working snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Justin's Homepage</title>
    </head>
    <body id="homepage">
        <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to Justin's Homepage!</h1>
        <p class="p1">Where would you like to travel next?</p>
        <select class="p1" id="location">
            <option value="interlaken.html">1. Interlaken</option>
            <option value="hokkaido.html" selected>2. Hokkaido</option>
            <option value="croatia.html">3. Croatia</option>
        </select>
        <div id="confirm">
            <form>
                <button class="p1" type="button" onclick="gotosite()">Confirm!</button>
                <script>
                    function gotosite(){
                        window.location.href = document.getElementById("location").value;
                    }
                </script>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The button is not being clicked.

```
<script>
    var location = document.getElementById("location").value;
```

`location` is a predefined variable in the global scope. You can't redeclare it there. Your assignment is going straight to the existing global `location`.

Since that line of code is outside of any function, it executes immediately.

Answer (score 0):

It indeed is what [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65412125/5934029) said.

You can fix it by using the code from the example above, or look at my example.
It is a little bit different.

The main difference is that I've placed the script just before the body closes.
And I did not use an onclick attribute on the button.

Instead I used an eventListener attached to your button. I prefer the eventListener as it does not nead to live inside the html.
You can simply create a js file `scripts.js` (`<script src="scripts.js"></script>`) and insert this code inside.
The advantage is that you only need to have this code once while you can have the same functionality on multiple pages.

Please note that I've also removed the `<form>` around the button. The reason for this is that you don't need it. You did add the `type="button"` which marks this button as simply a button instead of a form submit, so the form won't submit a `GET` request to itself, but as I've learned years ago; less is more.

Of course there is plenty more to tell and help you with, but I hope this gives you some insight in other ways to fix the same issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Justin's Homepage</title>
    </head>
    <body id="homepage">
        <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to Justin's Homepage!</h1>
        <p class="p1">Where would you like to travel next?</p>
        <select class="p1" id="location">
            <option value="interlaken.html">1. Interlaken</option>
            <option value="hokkaido.html" selected>2. Hokkaido</option>
            <option value="croatia.html">3. Croatia</option>
        </select>
        <div id="confirm">
            <button class="p1" type="button" >Confirm!</button>
        </div>
        <script>
            document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
              window.location.href = document.getElementById("location").value
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```